# MongoDb Node.js Querying Nested Objects not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to query for 2 dynamic properties using the node.js driver for mongodb.

Here's the data structure:

```
{
   "_id":"123456",
   "dateAdded":"2017-09-20T08:36:40.325Z",
   "followers":{
      "name1":{
         "followedOn":"2017-09-20T08:36:40.325Z",
         "unfollowedOn":null
      },
      "name2":{
         "followedOn":"2017-09-20T08:36:40.325Z",
         "unfollowedOn":null
      }
   }
}
```

Here's my code:

```
//Working but not dynamic
collections.find({ '_id': '123456', 'followers.name1': { $exists: false } })

//My failed attempt at making it dynamic
const id = "123456"
const username = "name1"

let query = {}
query['followers.'+username] = { $exists: true } 

collections.find( { "_id": id, query }
```

Note that this is not a duplicate of "how to make a dynamic key in an object literal". The .find() method of node.js mongodb driver does not accept object literals. I can't find documentation of what it accepts exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `_id` property needs to be within query object, not separate.

Here's how to do it:

```
let query = { _id: id };
query['followers.'+username] = { $exists: true } 

collections.find(query);
```